# SQL Server: Find Grand Father and Grand Son relationship in Father Son Column from Single table

Tags: sql-server

```
father_id     son_id
--------------------  
  A           B    
  B           C
```

Here A is father of B, and B is father of C.

I need a query to get A as grandfather and C as grandson

Comment: So what have you tried so far????

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the same table multiple times. This is one iteration that will only get you the grandson ID.

```
SELECT fb.son_id as grandson_id
FROM Family fa
JOIN Family fb on fb.father_id = fa.son_id
WHERE fa.father_id = :grandfather_id
```

Note that this is not exactly a performant solution if the table is large or the calls are frequent to the same relationship you will want to consider some local caching.

Answer (score 0):

A simple query like below will list all unique relationship of grandfather and grandsons

```
create table fsrelation (father_id varchar(100),son_id varchar(100));

insert into fsrelation  
values ('a','b'), ('b','c');

select distinct 
    A.father_id as grandfather,
    B.son_id as grandson 
from 
    fsrelation A
join 
    fsrelation B on A.son_id = B.father_id
```